# VB in Visual Studio Adding a class module will it have access for the form.vb I've built?

Tags: vb.net

Hello thanks for reading my question, I've build a user form with controls to control equipment via RS232 and USB. I've also added a separate class module "class.vb" to hold miscellaneous functions like writing to an ini file.

When I'm in the code section of the Form.vb and I type txb for text boxes that I have in the form visual studio pops up a nice list of all things in the form that start with txb.

However, when I do the same thing in my class.vb it does not do this and even if I type the whole thing such as txbModulation and then add the dot after it does not come up with the list of properties.

Does the class.vb have access to Form1.vb controls?

Comment: No, they don't have any access., as they're separate classes. Make the form pass all values (not controls) the class needs and make the class return the proper values and the form will handle the controls as it sees fit.

Comment: Probably not by default, what access modifiers have you set on your form controls?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "class module". Classes and modules are two different things. Either you added a class or you added a module. Presumably you added a class.

Comment: Forms are classes too. Every form class you add to your project inherits the `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class. When you add a control in the designer, some code is generated, including the declaration of a field (member variable) with the name you give the control. It's that field that Intellisense is listing. Just as you don't see fields from other classes listed by Intellisense in your form, so you don't see fields from your form listed in other classes. If you have an instance of a class (form or otherwise) and the field is public, then you can access that field of that object.

Comment: Thank you all for the great comments, I'm not a programmer but have done a lot of VB in Excel and this is my first time using visual studio, thanks for all the added info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I'm in the code section of the Form.vb and I type txb for text
>   boxes that I have in the form visual studio pops up a nice list of all
>   things in the form that start with txb.

This is because when you start typing a variable name, Visual Studio starts looking for a match.  It looks in block scope first (a for or while loop maybe), then at local (function/sub) scope, and finally at class level (a form is a class).  It will also look for any matches in Modules if you have them.  See [Scope in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope) for more info.

Since the Form and your INI Class are different, they cannot see each other unless you pass references or somehow pass values via parameters to subs/functions.